# warning: passing argument 1 of 'gets' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

gets() function takes one argument and this is a FILE-type. That's happening in my code but It doesn't work. I'm trying to get every single symbol from the file with a cycle like it happened in docs. What's the problem?
The error happens in the 'load' function. String: "while ((symbol = gets(file)) != EOF)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
} person;

void save(char way[100], person *object);
void load(char way[100]);

FILE *file;

int main(void)
{
    char way[100] = "D:\\Projects\\C\\C06_WorkingWithFiles\\C004_ReadingAndWritingStructures.dat";

    person object = {"Tom", 15};
    person *p_object = &object;
    save(way, p_object);
    load(way);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

void save(char way[100], person *object)
{
    if (fopen(way, "r") == NULL)
    {
        file = fopen(way, "w");
    }

    char *c = (char *)object;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(person); i++)
    {
        putc(*c, file);
        c++;
    }
}

void load(char way[100])
{
    if ((file = fopen(way, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("\nError");
        exit(0);
    }

    person object, *p_object = &object;
    char symbol, *c = (char *)p_object;

    while ((symbol = gets(file)) != EOF)
    {
        *c = symbol;
        c++;
    }

    printf("\nName: %s | Age: %d\n", p_object -> name, p_object -> age);
}
```

Comment: It seems you should use `getc` instead of `gets`. Voting to close <del>as typo</del> (ouch, I choose wrong reason...).

Comment: Piggybacking on @MikeCAT : gets returns a pointer and symbol is a char. That's the issue in your code.

Comment: But `getc` returns an int, and comparing `symbol` to EOF will not work.

Comment: maaaaaaan, i just wrote 'getc' like 'gets'. I'm so inattentive. Thank you guys

Comment: @nicomp to be a bit pedantic, the error message is not about the return type but the type of argument 1. `gets` expects a `char*` while it gets a `FILE*`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

i had to write 'getc' instead of 'gets' like this:

```
while ((symbol = getc(file)) != EOF)
```

Comment: Except now you can't properly detect `EOF` because `EOF` is an `int` and you're putting the value returned from `getc()` into a `char`.  There's a **reason** `getc()` returns `int` and not `char`.